# __init__() missing 1 required positional argument "arg" kivy error

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I am trying to code in kivy python but receiving this error again and again.
The error occurs in this class when I run it from the main class.

```
class SignupScreen(Screen):
    flag   = 0
    flag1  = 0
    flag2  = 0
    flag3  = 0
    flag4  = 0
    flag5  = 0
    flag6  = 0
    flag7  = 0
    flag8  = 0
    flag9  = 0
    flag10 = 0
    flag11 = 0
    flag12 = 0
    SQ1 = 0
    SQ2 = 0
    ssnType = 0

    def _update_rect(self, instance, value):
        self.rect.pos = instance.pos
        self.rect.size = instance.size

    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(SignupScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.sudoPwd = ""

        with self.canvas.before:
            Color(backgroundColor[0], backgroundColor[1], backgroundColor[2], backgroundColor[3])  # green; colors range from 0-1 instead of 0-255
            self.rect = Rectangle(size=self.size, pos=self.pos)

        self.bind(size = self._update_rect, pos=self._update_rect)
        self.captchaCorrectText = createCaptcha()
        self.ids['21'].reload()
        print ("signup captcha") ,self.captchaCorrectText
```

The error is in the init function on the line

```
super(SignupScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
```

Main Class Code:

```
screenManager = ScreenManager( transition = FadeTransition() )
if userDoesNotExists():
        screenManager.add_widget(SudoPasswordScreen ( name = 'sudoPasswordScreen' ) )
        screenManager.add_widget( SignupScreen( name = 'signupScreen' ) )
        screenManager.add_widget( OtpVerification( name = 'OTPVerification' ))
```

The code is working for other functions correctly. But it is not working for SignUp screen.
[image: Error]

It would be great if someone can help

Comment: Post the error as text, not an image. Also, post it all, not just part of it - you even skipped the last part that actually tells you what exception occurred

Comment: I have written it the main error is the title only  the missing argument one. The image is just for the line. The main error is required positional argument arg

Comment: Post the full error, as text, and ideally a minimal runnable example.

Comment: Do you know something about the error as I am making an application and the code for that is too long to be posted here, That is why I have posted the part in which there is an error

Comment: I can almost certainly resolve what your problem is, as can any other experienced Python user (the basic error means "you passed arguments wrong" so it's clear roughly where the problem is), but I'm not interested in digging through a poorly-explained example with missing pieces to work out exactly where your mistake is. It is always good practice to post a minimal example, with the full error traceback, and not to post code as an image. This helps any potential responder to find the answer quickly, it isn't about me - see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.